# Change color of some data points in a series of a plot in chart control

Tags: c++-cli

I am a newbie in C++/Cli world. My problem is I need to change the color of some data points in a series of chart control. I am able to change the color of a series at run time. But my requirement is, I don't want to change the series color, but only some particular data points during run time, based upon its value.

For changing the color of a series I used 
`this->chart2->Series["Test"]->Color = System::Drawing::Color::Red;`

In C# I have seen a solution like

`chart1.Series["Test"].Points[i].Color = Color.Blue;`

But I need a solution in C++/Cli. In my case `this->chart2->Series["Test"]->Points` does not have 'Color'.So what modification I have to do? Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:-

```
    chart1->Series->Clear();

    Series^ series1 = gcnew Series();

    series1->Name = "Series1";
    series1->Color = System::Drawing::Color::Green;
    series1->IsVisibleInLegend = false;
    series1->IsXValueIndexed = true;
    series1->ChartType = SeriesChartType::Line;

    chart1->Series->Add(series1);

    series1->Points->Add(0, 2);
    series1->Points->Add(1, 4);
    series1->Points->Add(2, 6);

    chart1->Series["Series1"]->Points[1]->Color = System::Drawing::Color::Red;

    chart1->Invalidate();
```

produced this chart: -

[image]

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I need that similar kind of output. For a single series multiple color based upon the value. In my case I am using the following step to add the points to a chart.          ```this->chart2->Series["Test"]->Points->AddXY(xaxis_time, Temp);```. If the value of "Temp" is greater than a threshold then that particular point should color with a different color otherwise with some other color.
In the above code  ```chart1->Series["Series1"]->Points[1]->Color = System::Drawing::Color::Red;``` in this line 'Points[1]'  means what? how will I do the same in my code?

Comment: Just after the point in your code where you add the points data, add an if statement:- if(Temp > threshold){ chart1->Series["Series1"]->Points[nnn]->Color = System::Drawing::Color::Red; }. Where nnn is the index for the point you have just added.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection?view=netframework-4.8